# Foundation 6.3.1 - validation message does not appear?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Why Foundation 6.3.1 form validation does not display the error message?

I follow this code from their site:

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">

<!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/plugins/foundation.abide.js"></script>

<form data-abide novalidate>
  <label>
    Amount
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-label">$</span>
      <input class="input-group-field" id="exampleNumberInput" type="number" required pattern="number"/>
    </div>
    <span class="form-error" data-form-error-for="exampleNumberInput">Amount is required.</span>
  </label>
  <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The text `Amount is required.` should appear when error occurs but it does not.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I deleted my answer.  I believe the 'data-form-error-for' is coming in foundation 6.4 - it's not in 6.3.1 - (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/9642).  Here's a codepen I found showing a current workaround using CSS: https://codepen.io/marcusconnor/pen/adpMrV

Comment: @genestd thanks for the links. I fixed it with some JavaScript workaround.

Comment: Hi @laukok, When you self-solve your question, this would be good to make StackOverflow readers benefit by posting it here.